# Issue With Responsive Masonry Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/tumblelog.html) for the layout of my website, everything works fine, but there is an issue with a responsiveness.
At the moment all elements are set to a width of 31.8% (also have some margins etc..) I was assuming that by resizing a browser window I will still keep 3 columns, but all element's would just decrease in width, however that was not the case, by resizing a window everything starts falling apart, I can't tell where this strange behaviour is coming from.

You can see my live demo site here: http://freshbeer.lv/test/index.html

I really don't know what is causing that strange behaviour, so I don't know which bit's of code to post here, if you know what bits could cause it, tell me and I'll add it here.

**Edit:** Interestingly, after resizing it and refreshing the window, it looks better, but not exactly correct.

Also I am trying to achieve something similar to this http://tympanus.net/codrops/collective/collective-57/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the width in Masonry too:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.content-box',
  columnWidth: function(width) {
    return width * (31.8 / 100);
  }
});
```

Comment: Now it just displays 1 column no matter what width

Comment: If you use padding try using `box-sizing: border-box`. I think it must have to do with the CSS. Try removing all margins and paddings and see if it works, then go from there.

Comment: Didn't work ;/ and I had box sizing there already, what I'm trying to achieve is something similar to this http://tympanus.net/codrops/collective/collective-57/ Maybe you have idea how they did it?

Comment: Holy crap I figured it out ;D thnx for help

Comment: Care to to share the answer?