# Why are there irregular margins when using masonry jquery with percentage widths in responsive container

Tags: jquery-masonry

I have done some searching on this site and have found a few questions relating to percentage widths of masonry blocks, but not quite this question. If i overlooked it, i apologize in advance.

My problem is that i am using masonry jquery to layout boxes within a responsive container, and i am setting the block widths and to percentages. It seems to work on the surface, but as soon as i resize my screen, the boxes and margins behave unpredictably (to me) and I haven't managed to wrap my brain around what's happening.

Ultimately, my intention is to change the percentage widths of the boxes with media queries at a few break-points (when i determine the columns are too narrow to leave the content—which will eventually be text—readable). But i haven't got to that point yet, because i noticed this behavior that i wasn't expecting.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/5Xn7T/27/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="myContainer">

<div id="myContent">

    <div id="myMasonry">    

        <div class="box height1"></div>
        <div class="box height2"></div>
        <div class="box height3"></div>

        <div class="box height2"></div>
        <div class="box height3"></div>
        <div class="box height1"></div>
        <div class="box height1"></div>
        <div class="box height2"></div>
        <div class="box height2"></div>
        <div class="box height3"></div>
        <div class="box height3"></div>
        <div class="box height1"></div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div><!--#myMasonry-->

</div><!--#myContent-->

</div><!--#myContainer-->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#myContainer {
max-width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 30px;
background-color:#D7D4F0;
}
#myContent {
width:100%;
background-color:#FFD2A3;
}
#myMasonry {
width:100%;
}
.box {
float:left;
width: 26%; 
padding:2%;
margin:0 3% 20px 0;
background:#666;
}
.height1 {
height:100px;
}
.height2 {
height:160px;
}
.height3 {
height:210px;
}
.clearfix {
clear:both;
}
```

Wow. Hope this wasn't too lengthy. Thanks in advance of anyone's help with this :)

Disclaimer: I confess the layout does not replicate my exact situation (the exact Javascript that i use is different, but i couldn't get the code i use to work in the fiddle, and my understanding of it is limited at best) and my actual HTML is a bit different (it's a child theme of WP twenty twelve, so the structure is a bit more complex), and while i understand that may defeat the point of posting here, this fiddle DOES replicate my issue, so i'm hoping it can be solved, or that I can be enlightened, based on this example.

**UPDATE: I just noticed that if i resize the window, it looks strange and creates strange margins (too small or too big), but if i actually refresh the page (when looking at full screen view of the fiddle) or update the fiddle, it then rearranges correctly. Hmm... is this just something i have to live with?**

**I found another question on SO with the exact same issue, but there is no solution posted: [Issue With Responsive Masonry Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822442/issue-with-responsive-masonry-layout) **